# Property of a divergent sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive real numbers satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

Let $\{a_n\}$ be an unbounded sequence of positive real numbers s. t. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$.

**Question:**

Is $a_n$ necessarily equal to a partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^n b_k$ of some sequence $\{b_k\}$ s. t. $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}b_k=0$, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k=\infty$?

---

**Thoughts:**

Since $\{a_n\}$ is an unbounded sequence of positive real numbers, I thought it must diverge.

On the other hand, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$ reminded me of the limits of the form $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}$, where also $x_n\to\infty$, which could be evaluated via *Stolz-Cesaro*, but the only examples of divergent sequences $\{a_n\}$ satisfying $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$ I could think of were the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^nb_k$ of a sequence $b_k$ converging to $0$.

However, my statement seems fragile and I'm pretty sceptical.

**Is there any counter-example?**

I also took into account sequences that contain infinite products, but, if the logarithms are involved, we could transform the product into a sum.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: just set $b_n:=a_n-a_{n-1}$ for $n\ge 1$ and $b_0:=a_0$

Comment: Indeed, if you want $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k$, then $b_k = a_n-a_{n-1}$ is the *only* possibility to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in the comment, if $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{b_k}$ then $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ is the only possibility. Therefore, you have $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}b_k=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k-a_{k-1}=0$.

The second part is more problematic since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{b_k} = \infty \iff \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k=\infty$ which is not guaranteed.
Check the following counter example:
$$a_n=\ln(n)(1+\sin(\sqrt{n})), n\ge1, a_0=0$$

Answer (score 0):

I later saw a bit trivial example of a divergent positive sequence $\{a_n\}$ with the property $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ worth mentioning: $a_n=\sqrt n$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=+\infty\quad\land\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=0$$